# How I can show Google Maps V2 into a custom dialog android

Tags: java, android, dialog, google-maps-android-api-2

Hello my name is Hernan so and I am a Android Developer. I make this question because I need insert a google map into a custom dialog I already have my dialog working ok but when I am adding the google map it throws an error in code. This is my code.

Java Code:

```
package com.sigetdriver.view.popup;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.sigetdriver.R;

public class InsertarDestinoPopup {

    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private Context context;
    public Dialog dialog;
    private Button btnCerrar;

    public void dialog(Context _context) {

        context = _context;
        dialog = new Dialog(_context);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_destino);
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        try {
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();
            pintarMapa();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        btnCerrar = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnCerrar);
        btnCerrar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();      

    }

    /**
     * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
     * */
    private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap(); // *******ERROR HERE******* 

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(context,
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    private void pintarMapa() {

        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); // false to disable

    }

}
```

XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCerrar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cerrar" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I dont know if it is the best way to make a dialog or showing a map into dialog, please I need solve this thanks in advance.

Hernan

Comment: whats the error it throws.Post the log-cat error.

Comment: i dont have error in logcat because I cant launch my friend :(

Comment: this the error into my eclipse http://imageshack.com/a/img33/1836/aiqv.png

Comment: k.then when it throws error.

Comment: sorry if I'm not clare this is my first time posting. My error appears when I write the posted code that can you see up

Comment: k.Use the map in fragment activity.

Comment: did you get the solution for your problem.

Comment: @Yugesh Please do not remove import statements from code, both because [you generally shouldn't edit code in questions except for formatting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88627/how-far-can-i-refactor-the-code-in-someone-elses-question) and because [complete, compilable code is preferable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). See also [this meta discussion triggered by your edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225674/editing-out-obvious-module-statements-import-include-use-require).

Comment: I cant solve it yet. I dont want a fragment activity because I need show my map in a popup better said into a custom dialog android. Please I hope someone can help me

Comment: @HernanParejaJordan k.One simple solution is you use normal activity as dialog.see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use activity as a dialog.Here you can do all normal activity methods.

**XML Coding**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Java Coding**

```
public class Map extends FragmentActivity {

private View rootView;

GoogleMap map;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
    setContentView(R.layout.map);

    this.rootView=findViewById(R.id.map_view);

    FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    SupportMapFragment mySupportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    map = mySupportMapFragment.getMap();
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        Rect rect = new Rect();
       rootView.getHitRect(rect);
       if (!rect.contains((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY())){
        setFinishOnTouchOutside(false); 
           return true;
       }
       return false;       
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {

        finish();
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

**Manifest File**

Here You change the activity as dialog.

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.mapindialog.Map"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
</activity>
```

Comment: Note that if you are using ActionBarActivity (or AppCompat theme), you'll need to use @style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog instead.

Answer (score 0):

base on your png, it seems like you're using support v4 package,in this case  you'll need to replace getFragmentManager with getSupportFragmentManager

Comment: I cant use getSupportFragmentManager i thing its because mi class is a dialog and not an activity. Any idea of how can I show a google map into a dialog box?